# Не находит элемент в словаре

Tags: python

Есть словарь:

```py
categories = {"Products" : ['продукты', 'еда']}
```

И такой код:

```py
categorie = input('Category:')
if categorie in categories:
  print('pass')
else:
  print('not found')
```

Проблема в том, что при вводе 'продукты' или 'еда' выводится сообщение 'not found', то есть такого элемента якобы нет

Comment: А как вы представляете работу словаря?

Comment: "Не находит элемент в словаре" у вас элемент список ['продукты', 'еда'] у которого ключ 'Products'

Comment: При обращении со словарём как с коллекцией из словаря берутся ключи. Вы проверяете вхождение введённого слова в список ключей словаря, а ключи вашего словаря это `["Products"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить ваш `if` на такой:

```
if categorie in categories['Products']:
```

у вас же в словаре `categories` всего один ключ 'Products' и в его значении искомый список.
Если в словаре `categories` еще категории-ключи которые содержат соответствующие списки и надо найти вхождение в объединенный список всех категорий то можно сформировать единый список по всем категориям. Вот пример вашей программы:

```
categories = {"Products" : ['продукты', 'еда'], "Products2" : ['продукты2', 'еда2']}

allcat=[]
for categorie in categories:
    allcat=allcat+categories[categorie]

categorie = input('Category:')
if categorie in allcat:
    print('pass')
else:
    print('not found')
```

Comment: А если предположить, что в словаре будут еще ключи, как тогда можно сделать?

Comment: а эти другие ключи тожа списки содержат? и итогом надо найти совпадение в объединенном списке всех ключей?

Answer (score 2):

Работать можно и с ключами и со значениями

```py
categories = {"Products" : ['продукты', 'еда']}
# Проверить ключ
if "Products" in categories.keys():
  print("Есть такой ключ")

# Проверить по значенимям
for value in categories.values():
  if 'продукты' in value:
    print("Есть такое значение")

# Или сразу по ключам и значениям
for key, value in categories.items():
  print(f"ключ - {key} -> значение - {value}")
```

Применительно к вашему коду

```py
categorie = input('Category:')
if categorie in categories.keys():
  print('pass')
else:
  print('not found')
```

Если вы ищете в значениях (из вопроса не очень понятно), тогда надо понимать, что внутри список и нужно спрашивать у него

```py
categorie = input('Category:')
for value in categories.values():
  if categorie in value:
    print('pass')
  else:
    print('not found')
```